# Determining when all nested React components have finished loading their data

Tags: reactjs

In my React app, I have tabs at the top of the app, a sidebar for navigation and a section to the right of the sidebar, and below the tabs that show content. When the user clicks on a tab, the sidebar loads its navigation data from the backend. Then after loading it, by default it selects the first item in the sidebar and loads the content details. The content details are made up of different components and several backend calls may need to be made.

What I would like to do is display a progress bar just above the tabs which is shown the moment the user clicks on the tab. The progress bar is only dismissed after the entire content for both the sidebar and content details has been loaded. The sidebar and content details do not update or are even shown until they have completely retrieved all their data from the backend and done any other initialization.

Determining exactly when all the content has been loaded is tricky as each component in the sidebar and content details are responsible for retrieving data from the backend. The only solution I could think of is for each component to implement a publisher/subscriber mechanism. Each parent component notifies each child component that it needs to load its data. When the child component receives this notification and has retrieved its data from the backend and finished any other initialization, it then notifies the parent that it has completed. Only when the top-level component gets all notifications from all its direct children, does it then dismiss the progress bar and cause the content to be displayed.

Another possible approach is to have only the first child component retrieve all the data from the backend on behalf of all the descendent components and cache it in the local repository. This would eliminate the need for descendent components from having to call the backend and could quickly just retrieve the data from the local repository. But there is still the issue of initializing each nested component. If I show the entire content while it is still in the initialization phase, the user would notice this. Still, I suspect React renders most stuff so fast that users will probably not notice it.

I'm not sure if this is the approach I should be taking or if there is something more inherent in React that handles this.

A similar website where you can see this is at Google's:

https://fuchsia.dev

although this site probably has much fewer backend calls than the one I am working on. But in general, this is close to what I am looking to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution with the subscriber pattern will work fine, but if you want something less complex, there are two common approaches:

If you are using redux, every child component dispatches that it is loading data right now with their unique id. When it finishes (or component is unmounted), it dispatches an action to remove the loading information. Parent component just checks redux store, if there is anything loading.

The second approach without redux is to pass a callback to the child components from the parent through props. This callback expects two parameters: unique id and bool value representing if the child components starts/finishes loading. When the child component starts loading, it calls the callback from the parent with a unique id and value true. When the child component finishes loading, it calls the callback again with the same unique id and value false. Parent component set to its state which child components are loading and renders the loading accordingly.

Comment: On your second approach, is there any need for the callback to be called twice? Why not just have it callback once, when it has completed loading its data?

Comment: you need to know when the loading started and when it finishes. The parent wouldn't know when the loading started otherwise or you need to implement different approach to know when the loading started.

Comment: Since the top component (the tab being clicked) was the one that started the chain of events, then there is no need for descendent components to know that. Each descendent only needs to know when its own descendents have completed and then notify its parent.

Comment: In that case you should be fine with calling the callback just once :)